# Google Bigquery: How can I create a table (saving results) programatically from the web UI query interface?

Tags: google-bigquery

We're using BigQuery via an API that seems to be mostly an interface to the Web UI Query / Results window, and I need to run a query there that creates intermediate results and then joins against them (solving the problem step-wise because BigQuery does not seem to support nested subqueries (with joins to the outer) or functions in join clauses).

I can do this in the BigQuery UI by running my first query (for the intermediate result set), getting the temp-table name from the Web UI's Query History, and running the second query joining against that, or by saving the result of the first query to a more permanent tablename in the UI.

Is there a way to, within the query, tell BigQuery to save the  output to a table - a syntactic equivalent of the destinationTable attributes in the python query configuration, for example?

Answer (score 0):

No. In the BigQuery UI there is no way to set destination table's attributes from within query!
Rather I suggest you to post question specific to your issue with "nested" query, so we can solve it